# How to add an icon to an existing exe file (without an icon by default)?

Tags: c#, .net

When I was searching on Google I found a useful class which let us change the icon of any `.exe` file using the following line of code :

```
WindowsFormsApplication1.IconInjector.InjectIcon("myfile.exe", "myicon.ico", 200, 1);
```

Where 200 and 1 are respectively icon `GroupID` and icon `BaseID` which I can determine using Resource Hacker. In this case the file's icon changes successfully without corrupting the file.

So i planned to use this class on my program which is a SFX / Software protector, the output file always hasn't an icon, all what I can see on Resource hacker is the below :

[image: Resource Hacker view of PuTTY_Protected.exe prechange]

i can't see  icon group id nor the base id, anyway, (I don't know what to put instead of 200 and 1 in this case)  So I tried to change the icon using the same line of code mentioned above, I used the following line of code (same as above):

```
WindowsFormsApplication1.IconInjector.InjectIcon("myfile.exe", "myicon.ico", 200, 1);
```

The file icon was successfully changed but the file doesn't work anymore!

When I tried to reopen the file using ResourceHacker, I found the below:

[image: Resource Hacker view of PuTTY_Protected.exe after change]

It seems that the icon resources were successfully added, but i can't figure out why the file doesn't work anymore, it seems that is corrupted.

[image: PuTTY_protected.exe has stopped working]

Any help would be appreciated.

Note : I tried using this class with unprotected file and it works like a charm!

The class I am using is the below:

```
// IconInjector.cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

/// <summary>
/// IconInjectorクラスの定義
/// </summary>
public class IconInjector
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    //static extern bool UpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, string lpType, string lpName, ushort wLanguage, IntPtr lpData, uint cbData);
    static extern int UpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, uint lpType, uint lpName, ushort wLanguage, byte[] lpData, uint cbData);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr BeginUpdateResource(string pFileName,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]bool bDeleteExistingResources);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool EndUpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, bool fDiscard);

    /// <summary>
    /// アプリケーションのメイン エントリ ポイントです。
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    public static void InjectIcon(string execFileName, string iconFileName, uint iconGroupID, uint iconBaseID)
    {
        const uint RT_ICON = 3;
        const uint RT_GROUP_ICON = 14;

        // アイコンファイルの読み込み
        IconFile iconFile = new IconFile();
        iconFile.Load(iconFileName);

        // リソースの更新開始
        IntPtr hUpdate = BeginUpdateResource(execFileName, false);
        Debug.Assert(hUpdate != IntPtr.Zero);

        // RT_GROUP_ICON 書き込み
        byte[] data = iconFile.CreateIconGroupData(iconBaseID);
        UpdateResource(hUpdate, RT_GROUP_ICON, iconGroupID, 0, data, (uint)data.Length);

        // RT_ICON書き込み
        for (int i = 0; i < iconFile.GetImageCount(); i++)
        {
            byte[] image = iconFile.GetImageData(i);
            UpdateResource(hUpdate, RT_ICON, (uint)(iconBaseID + i), 0, image, (uint)image.Length);
        }

        // リソースの更新終了
        EndUpdateResource(hUpdate, false);
    }
}
}
```

Any help or suggestion on adding the icon to the protected file without corrupting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the protection application is verifying that the contents of the file haven't been tampered with. Injecting an icon is definitely a form of tampering, and unless the protection software is updated to ignore it, it will always fail. Alternatively if you own the protection software you could update it to not strip the icons.

Comment: what about if the input file ( the file to protect ) hasn't an icon by default ?

Comment: @mohamedmaache: Will the protection system pass it on if you inject it  into the output executable if you inject it into the input executable? If so that should work.

Comment: Your solutions rocks ! It seems that i can change the input file's icon successfully without corrupting the file. Thankyou very much

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same issue with a 7zip Self-Extractor exe.

Updating the icon of the 7zS.sfx (instead of the exe) before creating the Self-Extractor exe does the trick and the exe is not corrupted.

Answer (score -1):

Your application's icon can be added to this executable with a tool like [Resource Hacker.](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)
 and visit http://georezo.net/jparis/MI_Enviro/Icons/adding_w_RH.htm