# embed resource to native exe from c#

Tags: c#, c++, embedded-resource

i want to embed a resource in a exe file using c#.

If i use c++ code it works well :

```
UpdateResource(hResource,RT_RCDATA,MAKEINTRESOURCE(104),
MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),(LPVOID)text,FileSize);
```

c# code that i use :

```
 IntPtr handle = BeginUpdateResource(this.NomeFileCryptato, false);
 IntPtr fileptr = ToPtr(encrypted);
 bool res = UpdateResource(handle, "RT_RCDATA", "104", 1040, fileptr,     Convert.ToUInt32(encrypted.Length));
 EndUpdateResource(handle, false);
```

Actualy, the c# code embed the resource in the exe file (let's call it a.exe) but if i embed the resource with c++, a.exe can read and extract, if i embed from c#, a.exe cannot.

any ideas?

---

this is the declaration for update resource in c# :

```
 [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool UpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, string lpType, string lpName, ushort wLanguage,   IntPtr lpData, uint cbData);
```

lpType and lpName are both strings and if i use
    UpdateResource(handle, "RT_RCDATA", "104", 1040, fileptr,     Convert.ToUInt32(encrypted.Length));
the  UpdateResource add the resource correctly to the exe.

The problem was on the c++. To reach the resource added from c# i have to use LPCSTR without the use of makeintresource macro.

```
LPCSTR nome = "CDATA";
LPCSTR tipo = "104";
hLibrary = LoadLibrary(this->filename);
hResource = FindResource(hLibrary, tipo, nome);
```

Thanks again for your time!

Comment: _'c# code that dosent work'_ is a bit too vague may be. That could be cause of the downvote. You might want to [**elaborate**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23986108/edit) on your particular problems.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be passing incorrect values, and since they're not shown, I assume your functions (`ToPtr`, `BeginUpdateResource`, `UpdateResource`, and `EndUpdateResource`) may be incorrectly defined as well.

Note that [`MAKEINTRESOURCE(104)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648029.aspx) casts the integer value 104 to a string pointer; it does not create a string with value `"104"`. Similarly `RT_RCDATA` is probably a macro for a value other than `"RT_RCDATA"`, such as [`MAKEINTRESOURCE(10)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648009.aspx).

So start from the beginning. What does your declaration of `UpdateResource` look like? I quickly found two contradictory examples:

- [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.UpdateResource)
- [How to add an icon to an existing exe file (without an icon by default)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9811076/89999) (in the question)

The first makes it hard to handle integer IDs; the second makes it hard to handle strings. I guess I would expect to use `IntPtr` for both the Type and Name parameters.

Once you sort that out, the next bit is understanding what the `MAKEINTRESOURCE` macro's equivalent is in C#. And that requires understanding how `MAKEINTRESOURCE` [smuggles integers in pointers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130925-00/?p=3123). Once you understand that, it's easy to tell what you need to pass here to pass the integers 104 or 10 into `UpdateResource`.

Comment: That is the part that confuse me because there isnt a makeintresource macro in c#. Yes, The RT_RCDATA is a macro for makeintresource(10), how can i call UpdateResource from c# correctly?

Comment: @user3374388 See my updates; let me know what's still confusing.

Comment: hi and thanks for your time. This is the declaration for updateresource in c# :    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool UpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, string lpType, string lpName, ushort wLanguage, IntPtr lpData, uint cbData);